# Kali live USB error

Tags: linux, usb, boot, kali-linux, live-usb

При загрузке выпадает сообщение (1 скрин):

> A start job is running for LSB:thin initscript

И я с ним ничего не могу сделать.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - не помогает, вылазит окно авторизации и тут же пропадает, а на экране появляются сообщения (2 скрин)

[image: 1 скрин]
[image: 2 скрин]

Comment: @VladSpirin ну, уж извини логи вытащить не смог

Comment: @VladSpirin хех, ну так что это может быть? У меня есть предположение, что что-то не так с нативным драйвером. Хотя могу быть не прав

Comment: А сама флешка сделана без косяков? Всмысле, работала до этого нормально? У меня похожая тема была с Калюхой, но на виртуальной машине. Только вот было это давненько, не помню как решил проблему.

Comment: Флешка сделана нормально